# Service Worker with optional forced update by get parameter

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, offline

I'm trying to build a custom service worker logic, which checks if a requested filename has a parameter added (e.g. index.html?update).If so it should try to provide the original file. If that failes, it should stick to the cached version.
I've come up with this solution, but the "update + offline case" results in an error.
As always thanks for any heads up.

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
    if (!skipSW) {
        event.respondWith(
            handleRequest(event)
                // here the error occurs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'catch')
                .catch(error => {
                    
                    console.log("Failed to fetch: " + event.request.url);
                    //console.table(event.request.url);
                })
        );
    }

});

function handleRequest(event, ignoreUpdate = false) {
    console.log("SW: Handle Request")

    // check if update flag is set 
    if (event.request.url.includes("?update") && !ignoreUpdate) {
        // true: try download original file
        fetch(event.request).then((response) => {
            return response;
            // false -> ignore parameter and use cache if possible by calling the function with an ignore update flag -> NOT WORKING
        }).catch((error) => {
            return handleRequest(event, true);
        })

    } else {
            //normal requests
            return cacheFirstNetwork(event);

    }
}
```